# No prompt, only cursor in gnome-terminal after start

Tags: gnome-terminal

Each time I open GNOME Terminal I have to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to use it. **It's pretty annoying**.

It starts with a cursor only (I can type, but hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> just moves the cursor to a new line so it's useless) and a window tittle saying: `Terminal` instead of what's in the prompt as it should. It's the same no matter how I start it (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, as a new tab or from another application) and as far as I can remember this behavior started for no discernible reason. And to my dismay it also survived an upgrade from `zesty` to `artful`.

I tried creating a new profile, but it didn't help.

I vaguely remember having the same issue a couple years ago and it just went away on its own. Somehow. I counted it's gonna be the same this time, but alas, no luck this time. It's been too long, the issue persists and it's driving me crazy. Help!

Comment: Maybe try replacing the `.profile` and the `.bashrc` files in your home folder with the default ones found in the `/etc/skel` folder.   I would backup the ones in your home folder first though.  And make sure you change the ownership of the files in your home folder to your user  `sudo chown $USER:$USER .profile .bashrc`

Comment: **Thx, this helped!** As it turns out a single `cowsay` line in `.bashrc` was the culprit: `cowsay -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows | shuf -n 1 | cut -d. -f1) $(whatis $(ls /bin) 2>/dev/null | shuf -n 1)`. If you care to make an answer out of this, I'll upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you don't have a [`cowsay`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowsay) line in your `.bashrc`. Something like:

`cowsay -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows | shuf -n 1 | cut -d. -f1) $(whatis $(ls /bin) 2>/dev/null | shuf -n 1)`

If you do, comment out/delete it.